Azure SQL database wakeup time
We're using Azure SQL database in the serverless tier. The dev instance, is set-up to autopause after 1h of inactivity.
A scheduled job, that executes during that sleep period, fails with the message Database 'dev-db' on server 'myserver.database.windows.net' is not currently available. Please retry the connection later. If the problem persists, contact customer support, and provide them the session tracing ID of '{guidhere}'.
Microsoft recommends to set the connection-timeout to at least 30s.. Our job's connection string already uses 4x that value and it still fails. The db is very leightweight in terms of size, if this might have anything to do with it.
Data Source=tcp:myserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=dev-db;Connect Timeout=120
Also DBContext is configured with retry options:
{
    string[] scopes = ["https://database.windows.net/"];
    string token = "token";
    string connStr = "Data Source=tcp:myserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=dev-db;Connect Timeout=120";
    SqlConnection connection = new() { ConnectionString = connStr, AccessToken = token };
    opt.UseSqlServer(connection, opt =>
    {
        opt.EnableRetryOnFailure(maxRetryCount: 10);
    });
}

Do you also experience long wakeup delays?

You need to retry not increase the timeout. The failure is instant - not a timeout. It won't wait until the connection timeout polling it to see if it is awake yet

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/serverless-tier-overview?view=azuresql&tabs=general-purpose#connectivity

Understood, thank you I will try this. But then the connect timeout property of the connection string is useless, right? What is it used for? And why does Microsoft recommend a value of at least 30s?

PS: The dbcontext is already configured with retry options. IIRC, the delay between attempts are 30s seconds by default, which makes this 5mins which should be enough.
opt.UseSqlServer(connection, opt => opt.EnableRetryOnFailure(maxRetryCount: 10));

Looks like there is an open issue to do this retry automatically https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/1957 - I don't use serverless SKU regularly so don't know if your experience is typical and what kind of retry policy you need in practice.

Database 'dev-db' on server 'myserver.database.windows.net' is not currently available. Please retry the connection later. If the problem persists, contact customer support, and provide them the session tracing ID of '{guidhere}'

According to the MS document

If a serverless database is paused, the first sign-in activity resumes the database and returns an error stating that the database is unavailable with error code 40613. Once the database is resumed, sign-in can be retried to establish connectivity.

That may be reason to get above error. To resolve it change service tier to “Basic (For less demanding workloads)” in azure SQL database as shown below:

For more information you can refer to below documents:

https://www.codejourney.net/how-to-fix-sqlexception-database-is-not-currently-available-on-azure-0x80131904/

https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/1957

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/troubleshoot-common-errors-issues?view=azuresql#transient-fault-error-messages-40197-40613-and-others



@baouss Please check if the solution helped you.
